# C-x C-f TAB TAB: Find file completion list: how to highlight subdirectories?

Tags: completion, find-file, sorting, directories, icicles

Often I'd like to open a file in a subdirectory. But poor me, I can't remember the name. So when typing `C-x C-f` and then `TAB TAB` for the completion list, the list of all files in this directory is listed, *including* the subdirectories, which are only marked by a `/` at the end.

Any idea how to highlight the subdirectories in this buffer `*Completions*` or to sort the completion list `directories first`?

Comment: Not what you asked for, but try to to enable `icomplete-mode` or `ido-mode` or install `ivy` or `helm`. all 4 are so called completion systems. the first 2 are build in, the last both can be installed with package manager.

Comment: @jue Thank you for naming these packages / modes. But in the answer of Drew was a direct solution posted, so I tried icicles first and by the way, the name is so funny (ok, deciding because you like the name isn't a really scientific way to make a decision, I know).

Comment: I never experienced icicles, but with the modes I mentioned you never have to remember any name, you see them right at the prompt. Try the oldest one with `M-x ido-mode` it just takes a minute. That once was a booster for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then:

- Directory candidates are highlighted in `*Completions*`.
- You can change the sort order for candidates any time during completion, using `C-,`.

If you customize option `icicle-file-sort` to the function `icicle-dirs-first-p` then directory candidates are sorted first: `M-x customize-option RET icicle-file-sort`.

Comment: I've spent more than one hour without success. The github files are two years old. The icecles-wizard crashes after downloading 10 files and EmacsWiki times out. Maybe wrong day, but please, Drew, get that package into elpa, melpa, whatever.

Comment: @KeksDose if you consider installing icicles, you could also (instead) consider installing `ivy` or `helm`, they are on melpa, you might like them.

Comment: @jue Meanwhile ... I got icicles running.

Comment: I can't vouch for whatever the GitHub mirror holds. Please download the Icicles source files from Emacs Wiki. People have no problem doing that.

Comment: @Drew Yes, manually downloaded them from Emacswiki. I found out that can get the help files with `M-x icicle-minibuffer-help` and then click on `Icicles Doc, Part 1`. It takes a while but then there is a lot of documentation. Will take a while to get through that.

Comment: @KeksDose: Yes, that way you can visit the doc in Emacs. You also have the same doc on the web, with some screenshots etc.: [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles).